# XIRR Calculation in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, irr

I am trying to do an `IRR` formula by group. However my formula keeps giving an error.

```
=IF(A2=A1," ",+XIRR(G:G,D:D,-0.1))
```

Can you please assist?[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Update**: After the PO added his data:

The `XIRR` range parameters should be something like `C2:C12` and `B2:B12`, not an entire column.

Try the formula below:

```
=IF(A2=A1," ",XIRR(C2:C12,B2:B12,-0.1))
```

**B.T.W** - in your title and your post you mention **IRR** function, but in your code you have **XIRR**, so which one are you trying to use ?

Comment: Apologies XIRR. Column A has the name of the Investments, Column G has the cashflows of these and Column D has the dates when the cashflows occurried. I am trying to get the IRR for each group of investments.

Comment: @James the IRR of each group ?

Comment: @James sorry, it's hard without seeing the data. Can you upload a screen0shot fo your data ? manipulate the values and names, so it will be hard to understand what it is

Comment: I have uploaded sample data . Not sure if you can see it . If not i can forward file to necessary person.

Comment: @James have you tried my edited Formula ? is it working as you intended ?

Answer (score 0):

Some guesses:

- Are you expecting a positive IRR? (That is the usual sign, so give a positive number as the last parameter)
- Are the dates in date format? (As opposed to text - Check that by pressing Ctrl+Shift+1 you can see numbers)
- Are the value numbers or empty?

The best would be, however, to see a screenshot of your worksheet and what exactly the the error is (e.g. #VALUE!, #REF!).

**Update**

You have the title row (Valuta and CCY conv) inside the referred range, these text data cause the problem, remove them by referring to C2:C12 and B2:B12 instead of C:C and C2:C12.

**Update 2**

I was experimenting how you could get a #NUMBER! error if you referred to C2:c12 instead of C:C.

Please make sure that the first number in the row is negative (I think the business logic behind this rule is that it is considered to be the initial investment value).

Comment: The IRR can be positive of negative. Date format if fine